# jQuery access value of text box

Tags: jquery

I'm probably overlooking something really stupid here but I can't find a solution anywhere.

I have a form on my site and I'm trying to access the value of a text input field with some jQuery.

If I do:

```
alert($("#id").val());
```

it works.

If I do:

```
var data = $("#id").val();
alert(data);
```

I just get "undefined".

How can I get the value of a text input box into a variable?

Comment: Working fine : http://jsfiddle.net/3H4UE/

Comment: Your variable assignment should work fine, can you post the code where this doesnt work?

Comment: Perhaps your jQuery is trying to access #id before it's rendered on the page? Check for document ready or move the jQuery code to the end of the html.

Comment: I bet that's it. An alert is initiated when the page is ready, but the variable is assigned earlier.

Comment: Is there a stackoverflow dimwit badge? Turned out there was a custom function removing the item from the DOM before I was trying to access it. D'oh.